# iPhone (non jailbreaked) device + custom keyboard

Tags: iphone, keyboard

Is there any opportunity to change default keyboard on iPhone (in any iPhone application) to any custom one, and is it possible to do on NON jailbreaked device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if there is an API to change all keyboards or add new keyboards, but if so, it can be done on a jailbroken iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

there are actually already different keyboards available :

- ASCII capable
- Numbers & Punctuation
- URL
- Number Pad
- Phone Pad
- Name Phone Pad
- Email Address

but if you want a more sofisticated or a complete custom one, you'll have to create a view with several buttons and modify those methods to hide the default keyboard :

- textViewShouldBeginEditing
- textViewDidBeginEditing:
- textViewShouldEndEditing
- textViewDidEndEditing

Comment: yeah, I know that it is possible in any special application to use their own keyboard, I wonder that is there an opportunity to create keyboard that will be rendered in every application on your iPhone